# How to Avoid Infinite Re-Rendering Loop When You Have to Set State in Render()?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a parent class component with states (startDate and EndDate) that get set by child component.
The child Component has date-picking components in it. See the code below for both parent and child components:

**Parent**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Child from './child-component'

class Parent extends Component {

state = {
  startDate: null,
  endDate: null,
}

startDSelected = (startD) => {
  this.setState({
    startDate: startD,
  })
}

endDSelected = (endD) => {
  this.setState({
    endDate: endD,
  })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child selectedStartDate={startDSelected} selectedEndDate={endDSelected}>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

export default Parent;
```

**Child**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import { DatePicker } from "antd"

class Child extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      startValue: null,
      endValue: null,
      endOpen: false,
    }
  }

  onStartChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      startValue: value
    })
  }

  onEndChange = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      endValue: value
    })
  }

  handleStartOpenChange = (open) => {
    if (!open) {
      this.setState({ endOpen: true })
    }
  }

  handleEndOpenChange = (open) => {
    this.setState({ endOpen: open })
  }

  datesGetChanged = () => {
    const { startValue, endValue } = this.state
    this.props.selectedStartDate(startValue)
    this.props.selectedEndDate(endValue)
  }

  render() {
    const { startValue, endValue, endOpen } = this.state
    this.datesGetChanged()
    return (
      <div style={{ display: `inline-block` }}>
        <DatePicker
          format="YYYY-MM-DD"
          value={startValue}
          placeholder="Start"
          onChange={this.onStartChange}
          onOpenChange={this.handleStartOpenChange}\
          />
          <DatePicker
          format="YYYY-MM-DD"
          value={endValue}
          placeholder="End"
          onChange={this.onEndChange}
          open={endOpen}
          onOpenChange={this.handleEndOpenChange}
          />
      </div>
    )
  }

}

export default Child;
```

So every time I need to set the parent states whenever new date values change in child component, I get infinite loop re-rendering. How to prevent this?

Comment: You should not call `setState` directly on render. You could [lift state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to the parent instead and pass it down as props.

Comment: the problem is that you don't have to set state in render function. Render function is meant to be a pure function, without any state changes. You have to lift your state up

Comment: Thanks guys!! Yes, I had to lift states up, and it worked awesomely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize a few comments I've seen, you should remove `this.datesGetChanged()` from your `render` function. If the parent's state must be updated when the child's state changes, then update the parent's state when the child's state changes. In your code, that would be the `onChange` functions on your date pickers.

`render` is something React does on its own schedule, and calling a state changing function inside it is a recipe for the infinite loops you describe.

To quote the React docs:

> The render() function should be pure, meaning that it does not modify component state, it returns the same result each time it’s invoked, and it does not directly interact with the browser.

[render docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render)

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

this.datesGetChanged()

}
```